# why can't I write to the standard input of my terminal device from another terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pty

I have two pts terminals open in my Gnome desktop manager Ubuntu.

What I am trying to do is to write something to the terminal /dev/pts/0 using the terminal /dev/pts/1  using redirection like:

```
##in pts/1
echo date > /dev/pts/0
```

But in pts/0, only date is simply printed and pressing enter doesn't execute it. So i guessed the comamnd is not going to the standard input of pts/0 .So I tried piping the output of `echo date` to /dev/pts/0  which gave me permission denied error to which i became root and changed permissions of it and still i couldn't get `date` command to run in pts/0 .

I am trying these things for learning purposes. So i really am confused how its all working here and what i should do to get it done.

Comment: If by "piping to /dev/pts/0" you mean `echo date | /dev/pts/0`, that fails because `/dev/pts/0` is not a program you can execute.

Comment: For clarification: Are you trying to inject text into the terminal as if the user had typed it? So if a shell is running in pts 0, `date` is put on the command line as if the user had typed `d` `a` `t` `e`?

Comment: "pressing enter doesn't execute it" - a terminal does not execute anything, do you mean the shell?  "not going to the standard input of pts/0" - a terminal does not have a standard input, a process does.  Again, do you mean the shell process which is using the terminal?

Comment: The command only get's printed on the terminal `/dev/pts/0`, see [mesg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mesg.1.html). The text doesn't get to the shell running there and will not 'execute'. Probably the simplest way to do something similar is to use `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: @melpomeme, Yes I'm trying to inject text into it and it worked but the text doesn't execute as a command or program. It just prints and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can do it by doing this commands, (from /dev/pts/1 or another tty):

exec 1>/dev/pts/0

#### to deactivate

exec 1>/dev/pts/1 #or your actually original tty address.

Basically you are supplanting the tty stdin.

#### Edited for more details.

"exec" in this case starts a new bash and you can feed this with a new set of environment variables that normally you can not change on the fly. For more details please do "man exec".

"1>/dev/pts/0" here we are saying, "whatever I type on this new bash, write it to this another one, and indeed it will do it, but all the stdout will be displayed at the original tty.

Good luck learning linux, I hope you enjoy it.

Answer (score 7):

Writing to a terminal device just prints output on the terminal. If it stuffed the text  back into the input buffer, then everything you printed to `stdout` would loop back into `stdin`, since they're both connected to the same terminal device.

In order to put data into a pseudo-tty's input buffer, you have to write to its master device. Unfortunately, they don't have distinct names in the filesystem on Linux. There's a single `/dev/ptmx` device, and the master process uses `grantpt()` to create a slave that's linked to it before spawning the child that uses it as its controlling terminal. So there's nothing in the filesystem that you can write to that will feed into the pty's input buffer.